# Returning multiple models with includes in Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have two models, Invitation and RSVP. An invitation has many rsvps and rsvp belongs to an invitation. I want to run a query that will return all invitations and the rsvps that belong to each invitation. I want to have all the attributes that belong to both invitation and rsvp. I'm aware of includes and have been trying things like

```
@results = RSVP.where(user_id: 3).includes(:invitation)
```

but I'm only getting the attributes of RSVP returned. I ideally want to have the attributes of the Invitation that RSVP belongs to added to the results. What concept am I missing or should I think of this a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that the `Invitation` model has two fields `event_name` and `event_date` that you want to access in your query results. You can customize the select list if provide a `joins` clause.

```
RSVP.select("rsvps.*, invitations.event_name invitation_event_name, 
  invitations.event_date invitation_event_date"
).where(user_id: 3).joins(:invitation).each do |rsvp|    
  puts rsvp.invitation_event_name, rsvp.invitation_event_date
end
```

Comment: When I run `RSVP.select("rsvps.*, invitations.event_name invitation_event_name, 
  invitations.event_date invitation_event_date"
).where(user_id: 3).joins(:invitation)`, I don't get the invitation fields in the query result. I have no idea why it's not working. It does return all of the fields from rsvp though.

Comment: The attributes are not shown when you print the object in the console. Have you tried to access them explicitly? i.e. `rsvp.invitation_event_name`

Comment: Ahh. I see that now. It works. Why does it not show in Rails Console?

Comment: In the console AR `inspect` method is used to display the object. The method lists only the fields from the model's table. Even when the object has dynamic attributes from a query result. Look at the source code for more details: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8dbf337e0a7e4db521aa2f5f992609fae98c329e/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L418

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

`RSVP.where(...)` with or without the `includes(...)` is going to return a collection of `RSVP` objects. By including the `:invitation` association each `RSVP` has, you're eager-loading the `:invitation` for each `RSVP` in the collection all at once. This prevents a separate `SELECT * FROM invitations WHERE ...` query from being run for every `RSVP` in the collection when you refer to it's `:invitation` association.

`.includes` is nothing but a query optimization if you plan on using an association for objects within a collection. It does **not** merge attributes from the association into the model instances in the result set.

If you want to have an attribute from the associated `Invitation` included **on** the `RSVP` instances, you can use Rails `delegate` method. You can read about it **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)**.

On your `RSVP` model you'd do something like this, listing out the desired attributes from `Invitation` in place of the placeholders I've left below.

```
class RSVP < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :invitation

  delegate :some_invitation_attribute, :another_invitation_attribute, to: :invitation
```

Now you can call `:some_invitation_attribute` and `:another_invitation_attribute` directly on an `RSVP` instance.

```
@results = RSVP.where(user_id: 3).includes(:invitation)
puts @results.first.some_invitation_attribute # delegates the .some_invitation_attribute method call to the associated Invitation
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't receive the invitation attributes from the query result.